# JavaScript, Memory Leaks, Garbage Collection. Trying for easy way out?

Tags: javascript, variables, garbage-collection

let's say I have a 'magical' function like so...  (magical will be explained)

```
var arr = ['hello','I','am','in','an','array'];  

(function() {
    var z = document.getElementById('z');
    //before edit: a = arr;

    //let's leak memory... for fun!
    z.onclick = function () {
        var something = ...; //something, the uglier the better :P
        //before edit: a.push(something);
        arr.push(something);
        something = null;  
    };

    //now lets say by doing so I 'magically' fix my memory leak
    //before edit: a = z = null;
    z = null; 
}());
```

But what if I was to do this instead...

```
//instead of a = z = null;
return null;
```

**By retuning null to my self invoking function would that mark all local variables (a, z) for garbage collection or would they still have reference within the browser and thus still take up memory?**

Note: I'm trying to take into consideration legacy browsers like ie7 amongst others. Also, I'm 'trying' to teach myself JavaScript so this might not make too much sense.

Comment: The return value does not affect which variables go out of scope (but you can still close over them and return the closure).

Comment: note that setting `a = null` in the IIFE will cause a TypeError in the click handler.

Comment: I don't think the environment is at play here. The environment should have no access to `a` or `z`, except through the event handler. Environment might play a role when collecting detached nodes (and subsequently their handler and _only then_ `a`) is concerned. As long as the node is attached, `a` must not be collected - even if you return `null` from the `a` scope.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak    The big question looming over me was if the return value could affect the local vars for garbage collection. In this case, it makes sense that it can not. Thank you for making that clear. Also, I'm gonna 'attempt' to iron out that TypeError. Thanks again.

Comment: Your edit has made my answer inconsistent.

Comment: Functions having no explicit return statement or returns nothing (`return;`), returns `undefined`. I don't think there would be significance difference if you return `null` (it may take an extra 4-bytes in memory)

Comment: @raghavv       I honestly don't mind changing my question back to how it was before. Your helping me out so if you prefer me to change it back just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have bound the closure function to onclick. The memory associated with 'var a' be maintained till you release the onclick handler.

> 1. Even if you don't set 'var a' to null, memory associate with 'var a' should be insignificant as 'var a' only has reference to a global object 'arr'.
> 2. Setting 'var z' to null has no effect.
> 3. If you could avoid using 'var a' in your closure then 'var a' will be freed up.
> 4. When click happens, function will get runtime error, as 'var a' is null.
> 5. **Returning null from the function has no significance in memory usage.**

Comment: Yes, it would. You may might as well drop the 'var a' declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I suppose instead of `var a = arr` & `a.push(something)` just `arr.push(something)` should help things?

Comment: @Terry replacing `a` with `arr` will save you a few bytes at best.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak    I understand the memory freed in not that much but it's the concepts and practices I'm trying to grasp. Like i said I'm teaching myself JavaScript. Thanks to yours and raghaw's comments and answers I have a better grasp of what's going on... Unless there is something more that I'm missing?

Comment: @Terry replacing `a` with `arr` will save you a few characters in the function definition and a reference-sized amount of space in the anonymous function scope. You could save a few extra bytes because the scope for the anonymous function is not referenced now (only if the scope is represented by an object internally). You don't release any memory that is concerned with the contents of `a`, as the very same content is referenced from `arr` as well.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak    Ok, I think i understand? The memory associated with `var a = arr` was minimal. More importantly the same memory (more or less) that would be reserved to `a` in the anonymous `onclick` function is still being reserved because `arr` is still being referenced in the anonymous `onlcik` function?

Comment: @Terry correct; note that the click handler is not the only one that sees the `arr`ay; since it resides in the global scope, it's readily available from anywhere and cannot be collected.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak    I apologize for dragging this on but I really do appreciate your responses. The only thing I can think of to improve things is to define another non-anonymous function outside of the self-invoked function's scope that the `onclick` function can point to? Would this help? Also, I mean no disrespect to raghavv but as shallow as a 'check-mark-accept' is it's the only way I can confirm appreciation. If you feel up to it post an 'answer' for me to 'check-mark-accept'.

Comment: @Terry As long as you get `arr` from the global scope (directly and indirectly), when the click handlers get collected, the array itself should no longer be reachable. I am not sure how are you trying to achieve the effect so I can't tell if it will actually work. Please don't hesitate to ask further.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak    The question that I have posted was purely hypothetical in practice and was meant for educational/clarification purposes. What I posted was an attempt, at my best knowledge, to set-up an environment to cause and resolve a memory leak. All of which I believed was done so in resolvable manner. What I thought was resolvable was far from true and much less then efficient. I still have a lot to learn... Again, thanks for all the help!